# Using PageController with NavigationController

Tags: objective-c, ios5, uinavigationcontroller, uipagecontrol

I am trying to implement a pageController within a Navigation Controller. For example

ViewController A -> ViewController b -> ViewController c (This Viewcontroller, "c"  contains a  PageController which has tutorial text along with images and audio). Thus I wish to use a page controller and be able to change between the pages that contain text, images and audio, however it does not push onto the NavController stack. At any page in the page controller the user can go back from "c" to "b".  Any idea's ?

Comment: Really? I dont think its that bad?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UIPageControl` works with in the View not on the `UINavigationController` Stack. If you want so then customize it. Or simply add the 'b','c' `ViewController` as a subView in `ViewController` 'a'.

Thanks.